# An example for a topological space which is not $\sigma$-compact but is Lindelöf and locally compact

Tags: general-topology

Is there an example for a topological space which is not [$\sigma$-compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-compact_space) but is [Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) and [locally compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space)?

Thank you

Comment: did you check Counterexamples in Topology?

Comment: Yes, didn't find any example there whcih satisfy all 3 requirments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is *locally compact* and *Lindelöf.* Every point $x\in X$ has an open nbgh $U^x$ contained in a compact set $K^x$. Then the open cover $\{U^x\}_{x\in X}$ has a countable subcover $\{U^{x_n}\}_{n\ge1}$ and so $X=\bigcup_n K^{x_n}$. Thus $X$ is a union of countably many compact sets: *$X$ is $\sigma$-compact*.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thank you!